# Ansible win_audit_policy_system module not changing the value

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, audit, winrm, ansible-facts

I'm using Ansible to provision a Windows Server 2016. This is the task I'm running:

```
- name: Ensure 'Audit System Extension' is set to 'Success and Failure'
  win_audit_policy_system:
    subcategory: Security System Extension
    audit_type: success, failure
```

output:

```
changed: [10.8.20.177] => {
    "changed": true,
    "current_audit_policy": {
        "security system extension": "success and failure"
    }
}
```

When I go to check on the machine if the change was really applied I find that it is not. I tried restarting the machine and it still didn't apply. 
Windows Server 2016 system audit policies shows the following

[image]

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

This command might give the expected result.

```
auditpol.exe /get /category:*
```

Microsoft mentioned something about this in the article below.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2573113/auditpol-and-local-security-policy-results-may-differ